# Rails html_safe notice when redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add icons to my notices in order to make them a little more human. However, the browser renders it as plaintext. I suspect that this has something to do with Rack and flash messages.

Here is the code in my controller:

```
redirect_to billing_index_path, 
  notice: "<i class='lnr lnr-checkmark-circle'></i> Payment method updated successfully!".html_safe
```

I've also tried `notice:("my_string").html_safe` and raw doesn't work with strings `notice:("my_string").raw`

**Question -- How can I get my string to render as html?**

Comment: It's no a valid html code, it's just a string with html code inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this in the past. I moved my raw or html_safe to the view

```
<% if flash[:notice].present? %>
  <div class='alert alert-info'>
    <%= raw flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I hope that this helps :)